# Scaling a figure in twocolumn environment

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column, resize, scale

I am trying to rescale a figure while in twocolumn environment, but all attempts result in error. Here is what doesn't give an error:

[image: picture 1]

I want to, however resize the picture, and when I try I get this error:

[image: picture 2]

I get errors with `\resizebox` and `\scalebox` too. Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of posting the code as a screenshout, could you please add  a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) directly to your question? This allows others to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: Having had a closer look at your code, replacing `\usepackage{graphics}` by `\usepackage{graphicx}` should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does “runaway argument” after \includegraphics mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434695/134144), [Problem inserting figure to LaTeX file using Texlipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37650/134144) or [Runaway argument error in IEEE template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409371/134144) See also: [Packages: graphics vs graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23075/134144)